# How do I fix Blazer Mobile App Startup Error?

Tags: c#, android, blazor, blazor-webassembly

**Problem Statement**
The application is able to successfully build for iOS and Android, but does not successfully compile. Android will throw an exception during startup. iOS compiles and after the app opens on the emulator, a white screen is displayed.

**Project Details**
Android Target Framework Android 9.0 (Pie)
iOS Deployment Target 8.0
Mobile C# Class Library built using .NET Standard 2.1
The Startup of the application should display a login screen and the login is using Azure AD B2C for securing sign in and sign up.

**Specific Android Error Message**
The error is happening in the OnCreate portion of the Android MainActivity.cs file.
Details from the screenshot are available on the next page.

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /wwwroot/  at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor (System.String root, Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.ExclusionFilters filters) [0x0004f] in :0   at Microsoft.MobileBlazorBindings.BlazorHybridHostExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilderContext hostBuilderContext, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder) [0x0001f] in C:\A\1\135\s\src\Microsoft.MobileBlazorBindings.WebView\BlazorHybridHostExtensions.cs:65

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqBPo.png)

Comment: What type of project is this? What IDE did you build this in?

Comment: @DevRacker - This is a Blazor WASM app. The app was built in Visual Studio 2019. The mobile Applications utilize Blazor Mobile Bindings and were built using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac and for Windows. Mac was used to run the iPhone simulator and Android simulators with no luck. Attempted to run the Android application from VS 2019 on Windows which had the errors described in the issue.